# Why is EMR Spark SQL's date_trunc function automatically casting timestamp to string?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm running a Spark SQL query on an EMR instance and it seems like the `date_trunc` function is converting a `timestamp` variable to `string`, which then results in NaN values. Below is my query and the output data

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc(start_time, 'HOUR'),
  item,
  count(*) as item_count
FROM schema.table
GROUP BY 1,2

date_trunc(CAST(start_time AS STRING), CAST(HOUR AS TIMESTAMP))| item | item_count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   NaN                                                         | A125 |  5
   NaN                                                         | BA85 |  2
   NaN                                                         | A81C |  6
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I've tried changing `start_time` to `cast(start_time as timestamp)` inside the `date_trunc` function, but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: The order is wrong. `date_trunc("Hour", datetime)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that fixed it. However, the Spark SQL documentation is wrong: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#date_trunc

Comment: Yeap, you are right. The example is wrong in the version 2.3.0 but it is fixed 2.4.0.